# How to find directory for File Output Stream in Android app?

Tags: java, android, storage

**I have an app which gets data from an Arduino via bluetooth. The data are written into various ArrayLists and saved in files afterwards. Here is the code:**

```
public boolean SaveValues(ArrayList<String> arrayList1, ArrayList<String> arrayList2, String valueType, String timeStart, String timeStop) {
    String filename = "File_" + valueType + "_" + timeStart + " bis " + timeStop;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    if(arrayList1.size() == 0)
        return false;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList1.size(); i++) {
            outputStream.write(arrayList1.get(i).getBytes());
            outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
            outputStream.write(arrayList2.get(i).getBytes());
            outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also save the `valuetype`, `timeStart` and `timeStop` into a database to be able to find the files. My problem is, that somehow the table where I save these values got deleted, so I am not able to find the files in the app. I would like to find the files maybe on the phone or something. Actually, I just need the filenames to be able to open them in the app, because they contain data I need. So, where can I find these files?

I have tried searching in the phones files. The files, and all the other apps data, should be saved in `Android/data/package-name` but I can't find the package name in `Android/data`. I also tried to search for "File_" in the files, because that's what every one of my files start with. But no file gets found.

Comment: check what `getFileStreamPath()` returns

Comment: thanks! It returns /data/data/com.lis.lis/files/'filename'. But I have to create a new file and pass it to `getFilesStreamPath()`. I don't know how I can find the old files, because when I go to the files on the phone, there is no /data/data/com.lis.lis.

Comment: you dint have to create anything, `openFileOutput()` docs say: *"Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist."*

Comment: My problem is, that I don't know the names of my files. The method `getFileStreamPath()` returns `/data/data/com.lis.lis/files/'filename'`. When I search in the phones internal storage, I can't find this path. There is just `Android/data/`, but in that directory I can't find the package-name of my app. So I don't know where I can find the files.

Comment: read `Context` javadocs - it has a method that returns the parent folder - you can use that parent folder when calling one of  `File.list*` methods

Comment: Could you explain a little further how I can read that? I am not that advanced

Comment: open `Context` documentation, type `^F` followed by `openFileOutput` and find every place they mention about it

Comment: Ok, I have found the `getFilesDir()` method, which returns the same as `getFilesStreamPath()`. When I want to get all the files, I have to use the method `File.listFiles()`. But this method doesn't exist. When I type `File.` , it only shows `File.listRoots()`, but not `File.listFiles()`.

Comment: what does `getFilesDir()` method return? what type is it?

Comment: it returns a File. I just cast it to String.

Comment: so you have `File` object, right? just call one of `list*` method on it

Comment: oh, now I got it. I have all the filenames! Thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome